# Cannot add outlook.com account to Gmail

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

I have been having great difficulty in adding my outlook.com to my Gmail account despite following the standard advice that I can find online (much of it being outdated).

Any help would be appreciated.

My trouble shooting thus far

1. Went to settings > Accounts and Import > Add a mail account
2. Entered my server info for my outlook.com account
3. Kept getting this error message

[image]

4. Enabled POP in outlook settings

[image]

5. Kept getting same error messages.

Comment: Here is a huge hint: Based on the error it appears you are using 2FA on your Microsoft Account which means you have to generate an (application password) so your Google Account can access your Microsoft Account

Comment: @Ramhound Okay is there another stack exchange site that could help me. Also I don't have two factor authentication enabled (I disabled it one year ago). Also I cannot find the application password page. Every mention to it I can find is outdated. I went to account > Security and Privacy > More Security settings and there is nothing on app passwords at all.

Comment: So neither account (Google nor Microsoft) is using 2FA?

Comment: gmail is using 2FA.

Comment: So I suspect your getting stuck at a point where Outlook is waiting for you to verify your identity.  Verify (again) you don't have 2FA [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12409/microsoft-account-app-passwords-two-step-verification).  [You also have to allow your Google Account access.](https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?mkt=en-US&refd=account.microsoft.com&refp=privacy).  If that still doesn't work, contact Outlook.com Support, they can help you figure out if something else is going on.